# Loki - Where is the update manager?

Tags: software-installation, updates, release-loki

I just installed loki 0.4 and was surprised to find the update manager missing. No more easy way to select package sources, drivers etc. Is that a bug or a design choice??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install manually that program with this :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk 
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

Comment: I'd found out before, but thanks nonetheless! :)

Answer (score 1):

Updates can be found and handled in AppCenter.

Packages sources modifications are difficult by default for security, the #1 cause of issues last release was PPAs, followed by hardware.