# package sources and mirror servers in loki

Tags: release-loki, updates, software-sources, sources, repositories

I noticed that the update manager is missing in loki and learned that updates are now handled by AppCenter:

[Loki - Where is the update manager?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7510/loki-where-is-the-update-manager)

I'd like to know the following:

1. how do I know which sources/repositories are activated and how can I change this if necessary?
2. what about choosing a mirror server? so far I've had considerably better download speeds when I selected a mirror close to me than with the standard download servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that you can get back the update manager by installing software properties:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
```

This will allow you to choose the sources and servers, just like in freya and Ubuntu.

EDIT: I wasn't precise since the update manager is another application - known from freya and taking care of system and application updates. you can install that one too:

```
sudo apt install update-manager
```

However, sources and servers are managed with software-properties-gtk